# Refactor a method to find records by status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently use .find_by_status(params[:status]) on my @tasks to find tasks that aren't closed or a sticky. (either 4,5).

```
def self.find_by_status(status)
  status = status.to_i
  if status == 0 then
    status = 1
  else
    status = status
  end
  if status == 1 || !status then
    Task.where(["STATUS NOT IN (4,5)"])
  else
    Task.where(:status => status)
  end
end
```

I also copied this for my tickets model too, to find only open tickets on the home page.

It's also accompanied by this

```
<% status_active = 1 %>
<% Task.new.statuses.each do |status| %>
  <li class="<%= if (params[:status].to_i || status_active) == status[0] then "active" end %>">
    <%= link_to status[1], :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :params => { :status => status[0] } %>
  </li>
```

I'm new to rails and I'm really struggling on refactoring this. I would probably prefer making those links into a drop down select filter, but that also I struggle with.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you want to improve with the refactoring?

Comment: It's not clear what you want, but some comments: 1) the variable "status" hold 3 (!) different values in the course of the method. Don't do that. Different values deserve different names. 2) Do not write `then`, that's not idiomatic. 3) `(4, 5)` Magic numbers, use class constants instead. 4) Use `condition ? value1 : value` for one-line conditionals. 5) Don't override `find_by_status`! AR automatically adds this method.

Comment: I went with the solution below, and took onboard uses class constants, I've wrote the following: Task.where.not(:status => [Task::CLOSED, Task::STICKY]) for the find by. I guess i should rename it to something other than find_by_status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet:

```
def self.find_by_status(status)
  if status.to_i.zero?
    Task.where(["STATUS NOT IN (4,5)"])
  else
    Task.where(:status => status.to_i)
  end
end
```

Is identical to your above code (There is no way that status can be false after you have cast it `to_i`).

You can clean the view code down to:

```
<% Task.new.statuses.each do |status| %>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if (params[:status].to_i || Task::STATUS_ACTIVE) == status[0] %>">
    <%= link_to status[1], :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :params => { :status => status[0] } %>
 </li>
<% end %>
```

I suggest adding STATUS_ACTIVE as a constant in your model instead of coding it into the view.

Also, the fact that you are specifying controllers and actions via param is strange but without knowing more about your use-case I cannot troubleshoot that.

Comment: Ah! That makes a lot of sense and is quite the eye opener. No idea why that didn't occur to me. The params are there as this table is partialed on a dashboard and on the tasks page. I don't want the page to redirect when on the dashboard.